# Perl guessing game - Saving data into hash

Tags: perl, hash, key

I have a problem writing a simple guessing game in Perl.

The game supposed to choose a number from the range 50-100.

There are 2 people in the game. Player and computer take turns the numbers until one of them guesses correctly.

Guess of each player supposed to be save as a hash where key is the guess number and the value is the number which user entered.

For example

User puts

56,53,67 and 67 is a match.

so it suppose to looks like this :

```
my %guesses = (1 => 56, 2 => 53, 3 => 67 )
```

I just started to learn Perl and I can not understand the hashes. Could you help me how to implement this part in code?

(I think there is also a mistake in a loop, cause it's not working correctly? )

Here is my code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

sub loot{
$lower_limit = 50;
$upper_limit = 100;

my $random_number = int(rand($upper_limit-$lower_limit)) + $lower_limit;
return $random_number;
}

my $number = loot;
my $counter = 0;
print $number;

print "\n";

my $state = false;

while( $state == true ){

    ++$counter;
    print "Pick number: \n";
    my $variable = <STDIN>;
    chomp($variable);


    if($variable == $number){
            print "You have won";
            print "\n";
            $state = true;
            printf "You made : $counter guesses.";

            exit;

        }
    else{

        print "--------- \n";
            my $a = loot;
            print "Computer guess it: $a ";
            print "\n";
            if($a == $number){
                $state = true;
                print "Computer won";
                print "\n";
                printf "Computer made : $counter guesses.";

                exit;
            }
    }
```

Comment: If you are mapping a strictly increasing sequence of integers with no gaps to data, the correct structure to use is an array not a hash.

Answer (score 2):

First, some feedback because you are just beginning to learn Perl.

1. Give meaningful names to things. Instead of `loot`, the subroutine picking the random number should be something like `rand_int_between`. The lower and upper bounds should be parameters to the function, not hard-coded in the body of the function.

   sub rand_int_between {
   my ($lo, $hi) = @_;
   return int(rand($hi - $lo) + $lo);
   }
2. Don't call the state variable `$state`. Instead, use something like `$keep_guessing` so conditions read more naturally. The clarity of your code is a reflection on the clarity of your thinking.
3. There are no builtin values `true` and `false` in Perl. Therefore, I suspect you slapped the `use strict` just for show, and your real code does not have it. Don't do that. It is there to help you.
4. Don't use a variable name like `$variable`. Instead use something meaningful like `$picked`.
5. If you are mapping a strictly increasing sequence of integers with no gaps to data, the correct structure to use is an array not a hash.
6. Hashes have no inherent order. That means, if you want to list all the moves the player made in order, you will have to waste cycles sorting those keys, whereas if you had just kept the moves in an array, it would naturally be sorted in play order.
7. Regardless, there is no hash in your script. You do not save the moves at all. You also do not specify what purpose the hash serves. So, one has to imagine what you might want to do with it.

With those points in mind, this is how one might write such a game:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use constant DEBUG => !!$ENV{DEBUG_GUESSING_GAME};

play( 50, 100 );

sub play {
    my ($lo, $hi) = @_;

    my $secret = rand_int_between($lo, $hi + 1);
    DEBUG
        and warn "Secret number is $secret\n";

    my %human_moves;
    my $turn;

    while ( 1 ) {
        ++ $turn;
        my $picked = human_picks($lo, $hi);

        $human_moves{ $turn } = $picked;

        if ( $secret == $picked ) {
            printf "You won after %d guesses\n", $turn;
            last;
        }

        $picked = computer_picks($lo, $hi);

        if ( $secret == $picked ) {
            printf "The computer won after %d turns\n", $turn;
            last;
        }
    }

    print "Your guesses were:\n";
    print "\t$human_moves{$_}\n" for sort { $a <=> $b } keys %human_moves;

    return;
}

sub computer_picks {
    return rand_int_between(@_);
}

sub human_picks {
    my ($lo, $hi) = @_;
    printf "Pick a number between %d and %d\n", $lo, $hi;
    my $input = <STDIN>;
    trim( $input );
    return $input;
}

sub trim {
    $_[0] =~ s/^\s+//;
    $_[0] =~ s/\s+\z//;
    return;
}

sub rand_int_between {
    my ($lo, $hi) = @_;
    return int(rand($hi - $lo) + $lo);
}
```

The line

```
$human_moves{ $turn } = $picked;
```

associates the current value of `$turn` with the number the human player picked.

`sort { $a <=> $b } keys %human_moves` sorts the keys of the `%human_moves` hash in numerical order, from the smallest to the largest (see `perldoc -f sort`).

Thus, the loop

```
print "\t$human_moves{$_}\n" for sort { $a <=> $b } keys %human_moves;
```

prints each number guessed in move order.

If you had saved the moves in an array, just

```
print "\t$_\n" for @human_moves;
```

would have sufficed.

Comment: Should be rand($hi-$lo+1)

Comment: @ysth `rand_int_between($lo, $hi + 1);`

Comment: So to get a rand int between 50 and 100 you call rand_int_between(50, 101)?  :(

Comment: @ysth I believe in half open intervals. You use `rand_int_between(50, 101)` only if you want `100` in the range of the function.

Comment: Thank you ! That was helpful